# HTML Email Removing underlines and styles being removed

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I have the following code being used as an email signature in Outlook 2016.

```
<style type="text/css">
a,a[href],a:hover{text-decoration: none; text-decoration:none !important;}
.contact a {color:#000000!important; text-decoration: none; text-decoration:none!important;}
</style>
```

In my html:

```
<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:14px; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; text-decoration: none !important;">
E: <span class="contact"><a href="mailto: test@example.com" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height:14px; color: #000000; text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration:none;">test@example.com</a></span>
</td>
```

The output (when I'm looking in gmail ) shows the email address as still being underlined, and I see my style rules being stripped from my anchor tag.

Here is the outputted HTML:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="line-height:10.5pt"><font size="2" color="black" face="Arial"><span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">E: <a href="mailto:%20test@example.com" target="_blank"><font color="black"><span style="color:black;text-decoration:none">test@example.com</span></font></a> <u></u><u></u></span></font></p>
```

Comment: Why do you have `text-decoration: none;` listed twice in your style sheet?

Comment: Try inlining it on the anchor tag. it will work and you have 4 `text-decoration:none`.